# cli connect to org dev hub not working

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli

I'm running `sfdx auth:web:login --setalias <alias> --instanceurl <instance url>` from a command prompt.

It opens a browser login page and I enter the credentials and hit enter. The browser goes blank and spins - does nothing while the command prompt is waiting. I don't think it's a proxy/firewall/virus protection issue. I have the auth 1.4.3 (1.4.3) plugin.
Seems like there are 100 ways that people have solved this. I tried many. Been at it for a while with no luck. Does anyone have this same issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
sfdx force:auth:device:login -d -a SomeAlias
```